# how to increaase the speed joomla loads

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I have a virtue mart website it takes forever to load.How do I increase the speed with which the site loads.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the global configuration and turn on caching!

Answer (score 1):

Buy a better server.

Comment: Joomla! is known to be slow, especially on shared hosting.  Such is the trade-off with out-of-the-box CMS solutions.